# Excel output in pentaho showing last month

Tags: excel, sql-server-2000, pentaho, data-integration

I´m working with PDI 4.1. I´ve created transformations and jobs, and I have an excel file with data from database. The columns in my excel file are `name`, `date` and `hour`, and I need to bring the data from last month. Can I do something like this?

```
Name_july_hour.xls==name_june_hour.xls
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've likely figured this out by now, but what you need to do is flow the data from last month's Excel file into a transform with a Microsoft Excel Input step. Then you can do what ever you want with it (aggregate it, join it with another file, join it with a database table, ... whatever) before writing it to the new month's file with the Excel Writer Step.